# fourier transformation and delta function about complex variable

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, fourier-transform

$$\delta(x)=\int e^{-ikx}dk $$
$$z=x+iy$$
$$\delta(z)=\int e^{-ikz} dk \;\;\rightarrow ??$$

Is it possible?? If it's possible, How can I proove this??
As i know, Fourier transform is defined only in real range.
And the reason that i have question about this, is that suddenly, complex
variable appear in my calculation. that calculation is some integration,
that integration has delta function and consisted in real value,

definitly, I did calculation in real range. then after i change varaible of integralation, delta function changed complex. it's so weird

How can i do....??

Comment: No it is not "possible". First of all, do you know what means "Fourier transform in the sense of distributions" ? Do you realize $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ikx}dk$ diverges for every $x$ ? What is true is with $T_a(x)=\int_{-a}^a e^{-ikx}dk$ then $\lim_{a \to \infty}T_a$ converges in the sense of distributions to $2\pi \delta$.

Comment: i can't understand... anyway you said what i put a complex number at that transform formula is not true right?

Comment: What do you not understand ? Do you realize $\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{-a}^a e^{-ikx}dk = \lim_{a \to \infty} \frac{e^{-ikx}}{-ix} |_{-a}^a = \lim_{a \to \infty} \frac{2 \sin(ax)}{x}$ diverges for every $x$ ?

Comment: No, Only when x is zero, that diverges. then what has relation with what i put complex variable in delta function??

Comment: That's the point : for any $x\ne 0$, it diverges because $\sin(ax)$ oscillates.

Comment: Then, How about case of iy?

Comment: Do you understand that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ikx}dk =\lim_{a \to \infty} \int_{-a}^a e^{-ikx}dk= \lim_{a \to \infty} \frac{2 \sin(ax)}{x}$ diverges for every $x$, real or complex ?